# uWSGI: No python application found

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, uwsgi

When I run my app with the command `python sorteerhoed.py && uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app` It runs fine and when I goto the server ip:5000 I get to see my page. But when I try to deamonize the server with systemctl it will start but the log gives errors.(http://prntscr.com/psyd02) And if I goto the website I have setup in nginx it says: "internal server error"

with this as my config files:

my nginx conf file:
http://prntscr.com/psye25

my sorteerhoed.ini file:
http://prntscr.com/psyb1l

my sorteerhoed.service file:
http://prntscr.com/psybjq

my wsgi.py file:
http://prntscr.com/psyg2q

I folowed this guide to install uWSGI with nginx: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04
And i already tried to use a different method to import my app in the wsgi.py file as suggested in different threads but this did not work.